# Dynamically Add Image To Infowindow

Tags: google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

I'm using the code below to load images onto a HTML page, which are pertient to the current 'Location' and 'User' id's.

```
<div id="galleria">
                  <?php
                    $dirlist = getFileList($galleryPath, true);
                    $x = 0;
                    foreach($dirlist as $file) { 
                        if((preg_match("/\.jpg$/", $file['name'])) or (preg_match("/\.jpeg$/", $file['name'])) or (preg_match("/\.png$/", $file['name'])) or (preg_match("/\.bmp$/", $file['name'])) or (preg_match("/\.gif$/", $file['name']))) { 
                            echo "<img src='{$file['name']}' />"; 
                            $x = 1;
                        }
                    }
                    if ($x == 0) {
                        echo "<img src='images/noimage.jpg' />";
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>
```

This works fine, but I'm having difficulty with two aspects of this. I'm trying to only show the first image and put that image in the 'Infowindow' rather than on the main page. But I have to be absolutely honest and say I'm not even sure where to begin. It's taken me a few days just to to get to this point.

The code below, is an **extract** from the script which creates the marker and the Infowindow.

```
downloadUrl("loadlocationfinds.php?locationid=<?php echo $lid?>", function(data) { 
            var xml = data.responseXML; 
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker"); 
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(); 
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) { 
            var findid = markers[i].getAttribute("findid"); 
            var locationid = markers[i].getAttribute("locationid"); 
            var findosgb36lat = markers[i].getAttribute("findosgb36lat");
            var findosgb36lon = markers[i].getAttribute("findosgb36lon");
            var findcategory = markers[i].getAttribute("findcategory"); 
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng( 
            parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("findosgb36lat")), 
            parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("findosgb36lon")));
            var html = "<span class='h3 orange'><strong>" + 'Item Found: ' + "</strong></span><br>" + finddescription + "<br>"; 
            var icon = customIcons[findcategory] || {}; 
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
            map: map, 
            position: point, 
            title: 'Click to view details', 
            icon: icon.icon, 
            shadow: icon.shadow,
            formfindosgb36lat: findosgb36lat,
            formfindosgb36lon: findosgb36lon,
            formfindcategory: findcategory,
            }); 
            bounds.extend(point); 
            map.fitBounds(bounds); 
            bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
            document.getElementById('findosgb36lat').value = this.formfindosgb36lat; 
            document.getElementById('findosgb36lon').value = this.formfindosgb36lon; 
            document.getElementById('findcategory').value = this.formfindcategory; 
            }); 
            } 
            }); 
            } 

            function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {     
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {         
            infoWindow.setContent(html);         
            infoWindow.open(map, marker, html);     
            }); 
            }
```

I just wondered whether someone may be able to take a look at this please and offers a little help so that I'm able to only show the first image within the 'Infowindwow'.

Many thanks and the kindest regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image is added to the html of the infowindow

ie

```
........................
var html = "<span class='h3 orange'><strong>" + 'Item Found: ' + "</strong></span><br>" +     finddescription + "<br>"; 
html+= "<img src=\"image.jpg\" alt=\"My Image\" height=\"Ypx\" width=\"Xpx\"><br>";
........................
```

Where **X** and **Y** are integers

[image: map]

Comment: Hi @david strachan, thank you for taking the time to reply to my post.I've changed my 'var HTML' row to:
`var html = "<span class='h3 orange'><strong>" + 'Item Found: ' + "</strong></span><br>" +     finddescription + "<br>"; 
html+= "<img src='{$file['name']}' />" alt=\"My Image\" height=\"y\" width=\"x\"><br>"`

However, I must have done something wrong because the map is no longer created on the page.

I just wondered whether you may be able to offer some guidance on where Ive gone wrong. Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: Hi @david strachan. I just wanted to give you an update. I've managed to get the images into the Infowindow, but I'm unable to resize the image. Using your suggestion my 'Var HTML' row is as follows:

`var html = "<span class='h3 orange'><strong>" + 'Item Found: ' + "</strong></span><br>" +     finddescription + "<br>"; 
html+= "<?php echo "<img src='{$file['name']}' />"?> height=\"10px\" width=\"10px\"><br>"`

I just wondered whether you could possibly take a look at this please and let offer some direction on where I may be going wrong?

Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: I was just about to post you about your typos but you beat me to it. Does changing `height=\"10px\" width=\"10px\"`to different values not fix this

Comment: Hi, thank you for taking the time to reply so quickly. Unfortunately, immaterial of the size I set, the image size doesn't change in the infowindow. Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: You are closing the img tag before sizes `html+= "<?php echo "<img src='{$file['name']}' />"?> height=\"10px\" width=\"10px\"><br>"` should be
 `html+= "<?php echo "<img src='{$file['name']}' " height=\"10px\" width=\"10px\"><br>"?>`

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for taking the time to put this together. I amended the line of code to match yours, but I received the following error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in /homepages/2/d333603417/htdocs/locationfindsmap.php on line 111` with line 111 being the line in question. 

I then added a `"` to the end, so that it closed the line off, but I still receive the same error.

I must admit I'm not too sure where I'm going wrong because the line, admitedly with the little knowledge I have looks ok.

Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry, I'm sure it's me being a little slow, but my line of code is:

`html+= "<?php echo "<img src='{$file['name']}' " height=\"10px\" width=\"10px\"><br>"?>";`

But, unfortunately, I'm still receiving either the same error or `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /homepages/2/d333603417/htdocs/locationfindsmap.php on line 111`. I've tried it with and without the `;` and the last `"`, but I just can't seem to get this to work.

Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: Hi, @david strachan, I just wanted to let you know that I've cracked it!

My code is: `html+= "<?php echo "<img src='{$file['name']}' "?> height=\"50px\" width=\"50px\"><br>"`

I just want to thank you for all your time, trouble and patience. I certainly couldn't have done it without you.

All the very best and kindest regards