# Unable to add parse image to custom Google Map info window

Tags: android, google-maps, infowindow

I am trying to add an image I have in parse to a google map info window, I can add the image from resource but I am unable to load my existing parse image to the image view inside my infowindow. I have loaded the image from parse in other areas of my app, but it seems that the info window is out of scope. Is there a way to load this parse image inside my infowindow? I do not want to use a resource file because the images are different in parse. The 2 sections of my code are below:

```
        class NearbyEventTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<Item>>
    {
        Random r;
        Context context;
        public NearbyEventTask(Context context){
            r = new Random();
            this.context = context;
        }
        public LatLng getRandomLocation(Location center, double radius) {
            // Convert radius from meters to degrees
            double radiusInDegrees = radius / 111000;

            double u = r.nextDouble();
            double v = r.nextDouble();
            double w = radiusInDegrees * Math.sqrt(u);
            double t = 2 * Math.PI * v;
            double lat = w * Math.cos(t);
            double lon = w * Math.sin(t);

            double new_lat = lat / Math.cos(center.getLongitude());
            return new LatLng(new_lat + center.getLatitude(), lon + center.getLongitude());
        }
        @Override
        protected ArrayList<Item> doInBackground(String... params) {
            ArrayList<Item> list = new ArrayList<Item>();
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Places");
            if(searchType!=null && searchType.length()>0) {
                ArrayList<String> types = new ArrayList<String>();
                for(String type: searchType.split("\\|")) types.add(type);
                query.whereContainedIn("category", types);
            }
            if(lastKnownLocation!=null) {
                query.whereNear("location", new ParseGeoPoint(lastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), lastKnownLocation.getLongitude()));
            }
            try {
                List<ParseObject> objects = query.find();
                for(ParseObject obj : objects){
                    ParseGeoPoint point = obj.getParseGeoPoint("location");
                    Item item = new Item(obj.getString("name"), obj.getString("category"), obj.getString("description"), point.getLatitude(), point.getLongitude());
                    item.vicinity = obj.getString("description") + " | "+obj.getDate("event_date");
                    list.add(item);
                    if(obj.getParseFile("icon")!=null) {
                        item.setIcon(obj.getParseFile("icon").getUrl());
                        item.downloadIcon(context);
                    }
                }
            } catch (ParseException e) {
            }
            return list;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final ArrayList<Item> arrayList) {
            if(isCancelled()) return;
            if(googleMap!=null) {
                googleMap.clear();
                mMarker2Item.clear();
                LatLngBounds.Builder boundBuilder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
                for (Item item : arrayList) {
                    MarkerOptions opts = new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(item.location())
                            .title(item.name);
                    if(item.iconBitmap!=null){
                        opts = opts.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(item.iconBitmap));
                    }
                    Marker newMarker = googleMap.addMarker(opts);
                    newMarker.setSnippet(item.vicinity);
                    mMarker2Item.put(newMarker, item);
                    boundBuilder.include(item.location());
                }
                try {


                    if (firstTime) {
                        firstTime = false;
                        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(boundBuilder.build(), 200);
                        googleMap.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);
                        googleMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate, 1000, null);
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {

                }
            } else mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    onPostExecute(arrayList);
                }
            }, 500);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        this.googleMap = googleMap;
        googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {

            // Use default InfoWindow frame
            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
                return null;
            }

            // Defines the contents of the InfoWindow
            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.maps_infowindow, null);
                v.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int) (mapFragment.getView().getMeasuredWidth() * .9), LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText(marker.getTitle());
                ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.desc)).setText(marker.getSnippet());
                ImageView icon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
                icon.getLayoutParams().height = 800; // OR
                icon.getLayoutParams().width = 800;


                ArrayList<Item> list = new ArrayList<Item>();
                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Places");
                if(searchType!=null && searchType.length()>0) {
                    ArrayList<String> types = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for(String type: searchType.split("\\|")) types.add(type);
                    query.whereContainedIn("icon", types);
                }
                try {
                    List<ParseObject> objects = query.find();

                    for(ParseObject obj : objects){
                        if(obj.getParseFile("icon")!=null) {

                            Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(obj.getParseFile("icon").getUrl()).into(icon, new MarkerCallback(marker));

                        }
                    }
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                }
                return v;

            }
        }

    );
```

CODE UPDATED: If you look at my NearbyEventTast class at the top, you can see how the code was implemented to get the data back from parse. I am trying to do the same thing by creating a new NearbyEventTast but I fail to load the correct image. It always shows the same image (I think its the first one in parse) and displays it for all objects instead of the corresponden image. Any idiea whats going on? Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried reading this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331774/dynamically-add-image-to-infowindow. You may also try to read the documentation how to load `domxml` to output XML: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3#outputxml

Answer (score 1):

As I am not much aware of Parse. But I have also face this issue to show a image from URL into info window.

First of all, the reason infowindow is not showing the downloaded image because MapFragment renders the view into a Canvas and then draws that. What you're seeing in the info window aren't the views you created, but a "picture" or "screenshot" of them. You basically need to call showInfoWindow() again on the Marker object, and that will re-render the Canvas and your image will now be visible.

Or you can use the [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) Library to load the image. I am using the Picasso callback option in my app.

First you need to create a Class that will implements a Picasso Callback Interface and in the Constructor recieve a marker to call a show info window when image loads.

```
 public static class MarkerCallback implements Callback {
    private Marker marker;


    public MarkerCallback(Marker marker) {
        this.marker = marker;
    }
    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
       if (marker != null && marker.isInfoWindowShown()) {
            marker.hideInfoWindow();
            marker.showInfoWindow();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onError() {
    }
}
```

How to use it.

```
public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) { 
            View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.maps_infowindow, null); 
            v.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int) (mapFragment.getView().getMeasuredWidth() * .9), LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
            ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText(marker.getTitle()); 
            ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.desc)).setText(marker.getSnippet()); 
            ImageView markerIcon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView5); 
            Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(imgUrl).into(markerIcon, new MarkerCallback(marker));
        }
```

**Hope this will help you.**

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply. I dont have much experience with libraries as I am still learning the logic of implementation. I am interested in the ShowInfoWindow() method.. Can I be a pain in the butt and ask for the first option example? Thank you very much!

Comment: Implementation of library is very simple you just need to add a this line into the gradle file  **compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'** under the dependencies.

Comment: First option will only works when you cache the image so that it won't make a network request for the same image to load into the marker when we call a ShowInfoWindow().

Comment: SO I will try to use the library.. Android Studio is asking me which callback to implement. Please take a look at the options here [IMG]http://i63.tinypic.com/2qdbm2r.png[/IMG]

Comment: You will need to install the library first, then you can implement the callback from Picasso.

Comment: ok great! I installed and found picasso, but I get an error. Please take a look here. I think I am almost there. Took a picture of the error here: [IMG]http://i66.tinypic.com/2q0j57m.png[/IMG]

Comment: Replace MainActivity.this with <your-class-name>.class .

Comment: PS : We need to pass a context to the Picasso.with() method.

Comment: My class is called MainActivity.. are we talking about a different class? Thank you :)

Comment: In which class you are using this Async Task. ?

Comment: Inside MainActivity sir

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115459/discussion-between-aman-jain-and-user3078406).

Comment: I managed to display the image from parse into the infowindow object. However, I am getting a random image not associated with the item inside the parse table. Perhaps you know whats going on? Do I need to get the image id from parse in order to show the correct image file?

Comment: Hello Again. I noticed that one reason I must not be loading the correct file is because I am using Picasso. You said, and I quote "First option -CallinfoWindow() - will only works when you cache the image so that it won't make a network request for the same image to load into the marker when we call a ShowInfoWindow()." ..... Right now I show one image for all files. Is it because I should use the first option? To call showInfoWindow?

Comment: THanks a lot! You saved me a lot of time!